# Highcharts skipping shared tooltip points for large data sets

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

Seems like Highcharts is skipping a few data points in the shared tooltip for high number of data points (2500+).

I am trying to render a dual axis chart with 2500+ data points for 4 series - using Highcharts. I am also using a **shared tooltip** option to render my custom tooltip html. But at times Highcharts skips 1 or 2 data points in the tooltip. For example, when I slowly hover over each of the points from left to right, then I am supposed to see '1st April' after '31st March'. But instead, I see '2nd April'. Is it a bug? Or am I missing something? (I have verified that all the dates are present in the categories passed to the Highcharts.)

```
tooltip: {
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false,
    shared: true, //show all series values together
    useHTML: true,
    // hideDelay: 50000,
    formatter: function() {
        if (props.config.type == 'pie') {
            return 'Value : ' + this.y;
        } else {
            let html = '<div class="fixed-tooltip">';
            html += formatTooltipDate(this.x);
            if (this.points &&
                this.points.length > 1 &&
                props.config.type != "combination") { //multiple series*(see note below)
                //*combination series are having 1 point, so handled in the else section as single series.
                let dateIndex = props.config.data.categories.indexOf(this.x);
                console.log(" date ", this.x);
                console.log(" dateIndex ", dateIndex);
                if (props.config.type == "dual") {
                    let dualAxisTitles = props.config.dualAxisTitles;
                    html += formatDualSeriesTooltipData(this.x, dateIndex, this.points, dualAxisTitles);
                } else {
                    html += formatMultiSeriesTooltipData(this.x, dateIndex, this.points);
                }
            } else { //single series
                //for combination charts have a custom tooltip logic
                if (props.config.type == "combination") {
                    let dateIndex = props.config.data.categories.indexOf(this.x);
                    html += formatMultiSeriesTooltipData(this.x, dateIndex, props.config.data.series);
                } else {
                    let seriesColor = this.points[0].point.series.color;
                    let seriesName = this.points[0].point.series.name;
                    let value = this.points[0].y;
                    html += formatSingleSeriesTooltipData(value);
                }

            }
            html += '</div>';
            return html;
        }
    }
}
```

Expected to see a tooltip for "1st April" data point, after "31st March". Instead seeing tooltip for "2nd April" data point.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Wenger, Could you provide us with some minimal live example? Everything seems to work well in the situation you described: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/omk4180p/

Comment: Hi ppotaczek, in that jsfiddle link you have provided, when I am hovering to right from "Jan 19, 20.52.29.723", should not the next point in the tooltip be : "Jan 19, 21.52.29.723" ? I am getting "Jan 19, 22.52.29.723" instead, always. Are you seeing the same behavior? ( Or, is that expected?)

Comment: Wenger, It depends on the width of the chart. If there is not enough space for points (1px for 1 point), they can overlap -I think that is expected behavior.

Comment: Got it! thanks. It shows all the points once I start zooming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points are skipped if there is no enough space for them in the plot area (1px for 1 point). The solution is to set a adequate chart width:

```
chart: {
    width: 1000
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yjk0ta43/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.width